# error javax.ejb.EJBException

Tags: java, aplicación-web, ejb

Hola tengo un problema estoy haciendo mi proyecto en Java Server Faces y al llevar a cabo un método de un controlador que he creado, le realizo el "debug" y hace todo lo que deberia hacer pero al final sale esto, gracias por ayudar.

Aquí está el stacktrace:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBException
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:752)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:702)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:507)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2084.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.Facade.__EJB31_Generated__PedidoFacade__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:434)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
        at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
        at com.Facade.PedidoFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.Controlador.ControladorPedido.generarPedido(ControladorPedido.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
        at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
        at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:748)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:691)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4314)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4291)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:521)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4233)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:507)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
        at com.Facade.AbstractFacade.create(AbstractFacade.java:26)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
        at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor790.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor791.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
        ... 63 more
```

El metodo usaddo es:

```
public String generarPedido() throws ParseException{
    FacesContext objFaces = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext objExternal = objFaces.getExternalContext();
    Map params = objExternal.getRequestParameterMap();
    Date fechaIn = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat formatoDeFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String fechaEntrega = "" + params.get("fechaE");
    Date fechaE= null;
    fechaE = formatoDeFecha.parse(fechaEntrega);

    Cliente cliente= new Cliente ();
    cliente.setCedulaCliente(Integer.parseInt(""+params.get("cedulaCliente")));
    pedido.setCedulaCliente(cliente);
    pedido.setUnidad(""+params.get("unidadProducto"));
    pedido.setCantidad(Integer.parseInt(""+params.get("cantidadProducto")));
    pedido.setClasificacion(""+params.get("clasificacionProducto"));
    pedido.setFechaEntrega(fechaE);
    pedido.setFechaDeSolicitud(fechaIn);
    pedido.setEstado("Pendiente");
    pedido.setUnidad(""+params.get("unidadProducto"));
    pedido.setPrecioTotal(Integer.parseInt(""+params.get("precioPedido")));
    pedido.setComentarios(""+params.get("comentariosPedido"));

    pedidof.create(pedido);
    return "";
}
```

La tabla es:

```
CREATE TABLE pedidos (
    idPedido int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    cedulaCliente int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    cantidad int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    clasificacion enum('baja','alta') NOT NULL,
    calificacion enum('1','2','3','4','5') DEFAULT NULL,
    fechaDeSolicitud date NOT NULL,
    fechaEntrega date NOT NULL,
    estado enum('Pendiente','Entregado','Cancelado') NOT NULL,
    unidad varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    precioTotal int(11) NOT NULL )
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Hola Lina. ¿Estás segura que tu tabla `pedidos` no tiene ninguna relación de llave foránea `FOREING KEY` definida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lee el rastreo de pila para mayor información. Tu problema se debe a error de validación.

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'
```

Deberías mirar tu clase `Cliente` y ver qué posibles campos no están recibiendo datos válidos. También puede ser que `pedido` sea `null` y al registrar insertará una foránea inexistente.